# Pass Data from MongoDB to Bootstrap Modal Using EJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, ejs

I'm building an express app which comprises `ejs and bootstrap` for rendering views, `node and express` for server side and `mongodb` for storage.

I have a form `(contained in a modal)` in which I can post data. After submitting the form, the values are saved to mongodb.

Here's the snippet for edit:

```
<td><%= cats.image %></td>
<td><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCategory" href="#">Edit</a>

// without using the modal above, I'll have to create a new page to edit only one item
// I think it's a waste of page space and bad UX, so I am going with the modal

<!--<a href="/admin/categories/edit-category/<%= cats._id %>">--> // I want to get the values from this id and show in the modal
<!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>-->
<!--</a>-->
</td>
```

When I click on the edit button, I want to get the id of the item and retrieve it's values to display in the modal.

Here's the full modal view:

```
<!-- Edit Category Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editCategory" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="/admin/categories/edit-cateory/<%=  %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myEditCategoryLabel">Edit Category</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label>Title</label>
                            // this value should come from the category id but don't know how to pass it
                            <input value="<%= %>" name="title" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Category Title"> <br>

                            <label>Upload Image</label>
                            <input class="form-control selImg" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="showImage.call(this)">
                            <img src="#" class="imgPreview" style="display: none; height: 100px; width: 100px">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Edits</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I pass the data from mongodb to the modal using ejs?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Store your ID somewhere: hidden inputs or data-attributes.

```
<tr data-id="<%= cats.id %>">
    <td><%= cats.image %></td>
    <td>
        <a type="button" class="edit" href="#">Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then, create an `onclick` event handler such that, upon clicking on the button,
 it will fetch the extra data via AJAX and [open the modal dynamically](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-usage) after you get a response.

```
$('a.edit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        modal = $('#editCategory');
    // make AJAX call passing the ID
    $.getJSON('/admin/categories/get-cateory/' + tr.data('id'), function (data) {
        // set values in modal
        modal.find('form').attr('action', '/admin/categories/get-cateory/' + tr.data('id') );
        modal.find('[name=title]').val( data.title );
        // open modal
        modal.modal('show');
    });
});
```

You will need to create a route for fetching a single object (I'll leave that to you)

```
app.get('/admin/categories/get-cateory/:id', function (req, res) {

    // TODO: fetch data using passed ID

    // once you have the data, simply send the JSON back
    res.json(data);
});
```

Comment: Okay. How do I call this route in express, as I have to fetch the data from db before passing it?

Comment: @JosephIbe This solution requires that you have all the necessary data when you build your table. If you want to fetch the extra data only upon clicking the Edit button, you would need to fetch the data via an AJAX call inside the `onclick` handler and wait for a response with the extra data before setting the modal's values and showing the modal.

Comment: Cool. How do I make AJAX calls to fetch data from mongo db?